# Is "I managed to locate the... Drugstore, was it? despite the lack of guidance" correct?

Tags: capitalization, ellipses

> "I managed to locate the... Drugstore, was it? despite the lack of guidance"

In this sentence, a rich, sheltered person is going to buy some common medicine from a 'drugstore', a term to which he is new and so is questioning the word.

Should I capitalize after the ellipsis, or after "*was it*?" since the sentence hasn't ended yet?

Comment: What are you trying to say with the sentence? It doesn't quite make sense.

Comment: Good question.  Though the language lawyers may claim foul, the punctuation of sentences like this is not well-defined, so you need to consider what best cues the reader as to your intent, plus what looks least "upsetting".  I wouldn't capitalize "drugstore", and have doubts about capitalizing "despite".

Comment: I wouldn't capitalize 'drugstore'.

Answer (score 2):

The ellipsis implies that the drugstore is a part of the sentence, and doesn't start a new one. Consider it as functioning as a comma. Despite should be capitilized since it starts a new thought. [Here are some examples to show this.](http://www.grammarbook.com/punctuation/ellipses.asp)

Comment: Yeah, in this case, when representing spoken words, the "..." simply implies a relatively long pause, as when someone is trying to think of the next word.  In other cases the same "..." notation would be known as "ellipsis", as it would represent words that are *elided* from the text, but in this case "ellipsis" is not technically correct (though it would still be the commonly-used term).